# Replacing HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, html

Hoping you guys can help with this.  I have thousands of these tables to convert.

Example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Institutional Metrics</td>
      <td>Institutional Targets</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>example 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For each `<td>` in the `<thead>` section it should be a `<th scope="col">`. Every first `<td>` in the `<tbody>` should be `<th scope="row">`.

I have tried a few different things, nothing seems to work. Any help would be great!

EDIT

I think what added to this is they are being imported from MS Word. So I've written so code to clean them up a bit.

```
function cleanUp(){

    var searchInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

    //clense it
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /\btd\s\w\w\w\w\w\W\W\d\d\d\W\s\w\w\w\w\w\w\W\W\w\w\w\W/g, 'td');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<td>)+/g, '<td>\n');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<tr>)/, '<thead>\n<tr>');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<\/tr>)/, '</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<\/table>)/, '</tbody>\n</table>');

    //replacement



    //output
    document.getElementById('updated').innerHTML = searchInput;
    document.getElementById('howTo').style.display ='block';

}

<div><textarea placeholder="Paste in your code" style="width:900px; height:300px;" id="userInput"></textarea></div>

<div><textarea style="width:900px; height:300px;" id="updated"></textarea></div>

<div>
    <button onclick="cleanUp()">Run Script</button>
    <br>
    <div id="howTo" style="display: none;"><p>Use the <strong>|</strong> for Excel data import and selection separation. <a id="download" href="">Download .txt file</a>.</p>

</div>
```

Updated - FINAL

Thanks everybody! Got it working!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function cleanUp(){

    var searchInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

    //clense it
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /\btd\s\w\w\w\w\w\W\W\d\d\d\W\s\w\w\w\w\w\w\W\W\w\w\w\W/g, 'td');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<td>)+/g, '<td>\n');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<tr>)/, '<thead>\n<tr>');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<\/tr>)/, '</tr>\n</thead>\n<tbody>');
    searchInput = searchInput.replace( /(<\/table>)/, '</tbody>\n</table>');

    //output
    document.getElementById('updated').innerHTML = searchInput;

    //final cleaning
    document.querySelectorAll('table > thead > tr > td').forEach(function(el) {
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.setAttribute("scope", "col");
      th.innerHTML = el.innerHTML
      el.parentNode.replaceChild(th, el);
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr > td:first-child').forEach(function(el) {
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.setAttribute("scope", "row");
      th.innerHTML = el.innerHTML
      el.parentNode.replaceChild(th, el);
    });

    var finalInput = document.getElementById('updated').innerHTML;

    //output
    document.getElementById('updatedFinal').innerHTML = finalInput;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Unclear what the goal is.... You want to replace the elements with JavaScript?

Comment: Specific find & replace potentially.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the tds in files, or are they in a document?

Comment: Correct. Basically the td elements in the thead need to be replaced with th, and anything in the tbody, only the first td element needs to be replaced.

Comment: are you open to a jquery solution?

Comment: They are all in 1 document

Comment: is jQuery an option for you?

Comment: Best solution, fix it on the file system.... Fixing it on the clientside is going to cause flashing of content since you have to wait for it to be loaded so you can select it and replace it.

Comment: Sure, if jQuery can do it, I am all for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well best thing is to change the markup itself. Anyway you can *replace* the `outerHTML` of the `td`s that need to be targeted - see demo below using vanilla javascript:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table > thead > tr > td'), function(e){
  e.outerHTML = '<th scope="row">' + e.innerHTML + '</th>';
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr > td:first-child'), function(e){
  e.outerHTML = '<th scope="row">' + e.innerHTML + '</th>';
});
```

```css
th[scope=row] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Institutional Metrics</td>
      <td>Institutional Targets</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>example 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Updated answer using `DOMParser` that converts a *html string* entered in a `textarea`:

```js
function cleanUp() {

  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var html = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById('userInput').value, "text/html");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(html.querySelectorAll('table > thead > tr > td'), function(e) {
    e.outerHTML = '<th scope="row">' + e.innerHTML + '</th>';
  });

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(html.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr > td:first-child'), function(e) {
    e.outerHTML = '<th scope="row">' + e.innerHTML + '</th>';
  });

  document.getElementById('updatedFinal').value = html.querySelector('table').outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div><textarea placeholder="Paste in your code" style="width:900px; height:300px;" id="userInput"></textarea></div>

<div>
  <button onclick="cleanUp()">Run Script</button>
</div>

<div><textarea style="width:900px; height:300px;" id="updatedFinal"></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative solution this could be use

**Code Sample:**

> **Note:** my code is inspired from @kukkuz's answer

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table > thead > tr > td').forEach(function(el) {
  var th = document.createElement("th");
  th.setAttribute("scope", "col");
  th.innerHTML = el.innerHTML
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(th, el);
});

document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr > td:first-child').forEach(function(el) {
  var th = document.createElement("th");
  th.setAttribute("scope", "row");
  th.innerHTML = el.innerHTML
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(th, el);
});
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th[scope=row] {
  color: red;
}

th[scope=col] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Institutional Metrics</td>
      <td>Institutional Targets</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>example 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceWith` method.

> `replaceWith` function replaces each element in the set of matched
>   elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements
>   that was removed.

```js
$('thead tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<th scope="col">'+$(this).html()+'</th>');
  });
});
$('tbody tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<th scope="row">'+$(this).html()+'</th>');
  });
});
console.log($('table').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Institutional Metrics</td>
      <td>Institutional Targets</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>example 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So you suggest that he should replace thousands of tables in runtime? On...the client side?

Comment: It won't be a at runtime. I am going to cut and paste them from word into the documents.

Comment: obviously you don't want to do that but you can't access the filesystem and manipulate files with a jquery script...

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceWith`. but it will replace the entire thing include text content. To keep the text content, first copy it to another variable and then append it to new element.

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var content = $('<th scope="col">');
  content.html($(this).html());
  $(this).replaceWith(content);
  
});
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
  var content = $('<th scope="row">');
  content.html($(this).html());
  $(this).replaceWith(content);
  
});

console.log($('table').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Institutional Metrics</td>
      <td>Institutional Targets</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>example</td>
      <td>example 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and pure JavaScript solution.

```
var theadTds = document.querySelectorAll('thead td')

theadTds.forEach(function(td){
  td.setAttribute("scope", "row")
})

var tbodyTds = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr>td:first-child')

tbodyTds.forEach(function(td){
  td.setAttribute("scope", "row")
})
```